# How do I string Split text in a text file into a text box and change the text of the radio button?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text file which contains a quiz of question and answer.

```
m1 | mcq | Which of the following is an animal | table#cat#keyboard#water

m2 | mcq | which of the following is a programming language |C++#water#Air#Phone

m3 | mcq | which is the prime number | 3#4#8#10
```

I have try to split a text or string in a text file into a textbox, For example, Which of the following is an animal

This is my code:

```
try 
{
    ReadQuestionTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\ip700\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\FYP Project\\FYP Project\\bin\\Debug\\RichTextBox.txt");
}
catch
{
    ReadQuestionTextBox.Text = "Could not read file";
}
```

I am trying to go further by using more complicated part of string split where I am able to determine the location of the text in text file where text like

Which of the following is an animal? into a text box and my answer choice split into 4 radio button, `table#cat#keyboard#water`.

I got confused on how to proceed as I'm still new to C# WPF

About string split, I know how to split a line of text in the text file into a listbox.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As your question is now it is difficult to understand what you are asking exactly. Because as I read your question now it seems as if you are asking us to write the parser for the format in that textfile. Which is not what SO is for. So could you edit your question so it becomes more specific to what you are asking please?

Comment: Oh sorry. Is this title ok?

Comment: How do I string Split text in a text file into a text box and change the text of the radio button?

Comment: I only know about parseint but i have no heard about parser for the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to read the contents of the file into a variable, not the text box itself.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename");
```

If each line of your file is a new question then each element in the string array will hold the question to parse.

Then to parse each question you could loop over the array and use string split again. Here's how you might setup one question with its options.

```
string[] line = lines[0].Split("|", split options);
string question = line[2].Trim();
string[] options = line[3].Split("#", split options);
```

string split options can be `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` which removes empty entries from the array or `StringSplitOptions.None` which preserves them.

Then you could loop through options and create and add a new radio button to the form for each option.

It doesn't look like your text file contains the answers to the questions so you may want to add that.

Comment: Do I need to specify the filename path?

Comment: Yeah. It works the same way as the method you were using (ReadAllText) but instead of reading the file in as one string its an array of strings with each line in the file in the file a new element in the array.

Comment: what does split option mean? I have never use stringsplitoption before

Comment: StringSplitOption is a parameter you can pass into split to tell split how it should handle empty entries. Remove them or keep them.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How do I convert multiple radio button text? Im fine with changing the textbox text as i usually do this, textbox.text = File.(something) But i am not sure how to do in radio button or checkbox as they do not have .Text

Comment: It's been ages since I've done any sort of UI work, but they have a caption don't they? If not then just use a Label for the text of the radio button.

Comment: Wait, u mean u can insert a label inside a radio button?

Comment: With WPF you can. But you could also just put a label next to a radio button too. Google it :p

Comment: I wanted to create a loop for the radio button so that my option can be insert into 4 label which is inside radio button. but im only familiar with if..else. I would like some guidance.